# Entity Framework 7 - How to add a dynamic entity to the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to work out how to add a dynamically created class to the Model in my DbContext.

I have a small C# console app which uses EF 7.  I have a class called *Bob* which inherits from *BaseTable*. Both are in a code (.cs) file and get compiled into the app and used in by DbContext as DbSet...

When I check the model at runtime, I can see the class there.

Then I create a new entity called *Fred* which also inherits from *BaseTable* using *CSharpCompilation* with appropriate getters and setters.

The issue I have, is how to add it to the model?.

My call to the *CSharpCompilation* routine returns a *Type*?.  I have tried Set just before I want to use it, and also in OnModelCreating using RegisterAllEntities which is my preferred choice. The former won't compile, and the latter does not appear to find the class at runtime.

Does anyone have a code snippet or example on how to add a dynamic class to the model?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer, so thought I would post it for future reference.

In my routine that creates the dynamic entity (class), after the call to Emit(), if the result was Success, I load the result into a new assembly using Assembly.Load.

What I needed to do was call GetExportedTypes().ToList() on the new assembly, then  enumerate through the result calling builder.Entity(t) where t is the type of the new entity from the enumeration.

builder is used in OnModelCreating() so I was able to add my new entity there.